# Uncaught ReferenceError: s is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Por qué obtengo este error?

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: s is not defined
>     at adjustWindow (functions.js:111)
>     at functions.js:85
> ```

Este es mi código:

```js
// Call Main Slider 
jQuery('#main-slider').slippry({
  // general elements & wrapper


  // options
  adaptiveHeight: false, // height of the sliders adapts to current slide
  start: '1', // num (starting from 1), random
  loop: true, // first -> last & last -> first arrows
  captionsSrc: 'li',
  captions: 'custom', // Position: overlay, below, custom, false
  captionsEl: '.external-captions',

  // transitions
  transition: 'fade', // fade, horizontal, kenburns, false
  easing: 'linear', // easing to use in the animation [(see... [jquery www])]
  continuous: false,

  // slideshow
  auto: true
});

// Call Services Slider 
jQuery('#services-slider').slippry({
  // general elements & wrapper


  // options
  adaptiveHeight: false, // height of the sliders adapts to current slide
  start: '1', // num (starting from 1), random
  loop: false, // first -> last & last -> first arrows
  captionsSrc: 'li',
  captions: 'custom', // Position: overlay, below, custom, false
  captionsEl: '.external-captions',

  // transitions
  transition: 'horizontal', // fade, horizontal, kenburns, false
  easing: 'linear', // easing to use in the animation [(see... [jquery www])]
  continuous: true,

  // slideshow
  auto: false
});

// Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
jQuery(".navbar a").on('click touch', function (event) {
  'use strict';
  // Get a safe height for scrolling to

  // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
  if (this.hash !== "") {

    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;

    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
    // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800, function () {

      // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });

  } // End if

});

$(document).ready(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  // Setup variables
  var $window = $(window);
  var $slide = $('.homeSlide');
  var $body = $('body');

  //FadeIn all sections   
  $body.imagesLoaded(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {

      // Resize sections
      adjustWindow();

      // Fade in sections
      $body.removeClass('loading').addClass('loaded');

    }, 800);
  });

  function adjustWindow() {


    if (!(/Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i).test(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera)) {
      skrollr.init({
        forceHeight: false
      });
    }

    // Get window size
    var winH = $window.height();

    // Keep minimum height 500
    if (winH <= 500) {
      winH = 500;
    }

    // Refresh Skrollr after resizing our sections
    s.refresh($('.homeSlide'));

  }

});

(function ($) {
  "use strict";

  function count($this) {
    var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
    current = current + 1; /* Where 50 is increment */
    $this.html(++current);
    if (current > $this.data('count')) {
      $this.html($this.data('count'));
    } else {
      setTimeout(function () {
        count($this);
      }, 50);
    }
  }
  $(".stat-count").each(function () {
    $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
    $(this).html('0');
    count($(this));
  });
})(jQuery);

window.onscroll = function () {
  'use strict';
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  'use strict';
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  'use strict';
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 1000);
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For IE and Firefox
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Agrega una url a las librerias que estas usando. (slippry). Y si tienes html tambien agregalo. Echale un ojo a [ask].

Comment: Ag, bienvenid@ a SOes. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour]. Pues basicamente el error dice que "s" no esta definido. Supongo que es esta parte `s.refresh($('.homeSlide'));` en la funcion `adjustWindow()` y ciertamente no veo esa variable definida por ninguna parte

Comment: Quizás la solución sea cambiar `s.refresh` por `Skrollr.prototype.refresh`.

Comment: Mil gracias a todos, consulto aquí porque en realidad hago diseño, y este código ya viene en el paquete, si bien la pagina funciona bien, en la consola me da este error. Hice el cambio sugerido de s.refresh por Skrollr...pero no surte efecto.

Comment: Aquí dejo link con los archivos tanto html, css, como js: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V9lGS7XAk2ZmBlOAhXV76mlMrbJGT7g_

Answer (score 1):

En la función adjustWindow estás llamando a una variable s que no está definida:

```
// Refresh Skrollr after resizing our sections
s.refresh($('.homeSlide'));
```